# SQL Server Standard / SQL Server Express side-by-side

Tags: sql-server

I'm new to SQL Server, so apologies if my question sounds stupid.

I'm looking to move next step from Access trying to bring in SQL Server Standard in our company but my boss is not happy to purchase SQL Server Standard for every region/country where our company operates, he says it'll increase our cost. At the moment we're using Access DB in different regions and it's all messy.

My question is, can I use SQL Server Standard on central DB server and SQL Server Express on all other regional servers please? Can we connect instances on Express editions to Standard editions?

Point is that I'll keep on learning and improve skills on SQL Server Standard and use it to connect with all other regional offices using Express Edition as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't need the express editions to be installed in all other regional if you are using SQL Server as Central Data Server and your regions are able to do connection to the server.

Your app will have connection string like this
http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/creating-a-connection-string

The data source itself is the instance of the SQL Server that you installed in the Central Data Server.